# Minimum expected value

Tags: probability

Given a line of length 1, a point on that line is chosen (Uniform distribution).
$X$ would be the distance from the begining of the line to the point.
$Y$ would be the distance from the end of the line to the point.

Why does $E(min\{X,Y\}) = 0.25$ ?

Please no leading questions, or hints, just need a proper explanation.

Comment: Let $Z$ be the point on the line; then $E(\min(X,Y)) = E[Z \mid Z<0.5]/2 + E[1 - Z\mid Z>0.5]/2 = 0.25/2 + 0.25/2  = 0.25$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously $\min\{X,Y\}$ cannot be larger than $0.5$, as that is the value when you choose the point exactly in the middle. Since it also doesn't matter whether you choose a point left or right to the middle, you can just map any point with $X>0.5$ to the symmetric point.

It therefore is obvious that $\min\{X,Y\}$ is uniformly distributed between $0$ and $0.5$. And the expectation value of an uniform distribution on an interval is the middle of the interval, which in this case is $0.25$.

Answer (score 2):

$E(\min\{X,Y\}|X=t)=\cases{t, & t<0.5\\1-t, & t>0.5}$, So $E(\min\{X,Y\})=\int_0^1 E(\min\{X,Y\}|X=t) dt=\int_0^{0.5}t\ dt+dt=\int_{0.5}^{1}1-t\ dt\ =\ 0.125 + 0.125=0.25$

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard to see min(X,Y) is uniform on [0, 0.5].